# MySQL: Return rows below X ID after ORDER?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently using the following code:

```
SELECT at.article_id, art.datetime, Count(at.article_id) AS common_tagged_art
FROM article_tags AS at INNER JOIN articles AS art ON at.article_id = art.article_id
WHERE at.tag_id = 4 OR at.tag_id = 3 OR at.tag_id = 1
GROUP BY at.article_id
ORDER BY common_tagged_art DESC, art.datetime DESC
```

This returns almost the exact result set I need, which look something like:

```
+-----------+---------------------+-------------+
| article_id| datetime            | common_tags |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------+
|     23    | 2012-09-25 15:37:25 |      3      |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------+
|     24    | 2012-09-25 15:37:24 |      3      |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------+
|     27    | 2012-09-25 15:37:23 |      3      |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------+
|     30    | 2012-09-25 15:37:22 |      3      |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------+
|     21    | 2012-09-25 15:37:21 |      3      |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------+
```

I need to adjust my query so that I am able to figure out that article_id 24 is on the 2nd row of the results I get back, then I need it to return everything below the 2nd row.

If there were 100 rows in a subquery and I identified that article_id 24 was on the 49th row, I need the query to return rows 50-100. I'm not sure if this is possible in MySQL, or if it would be a better suited task to do within PHP given my original query.

What I have so far looks something like the following, only, I'm at a loss after the subquery.

```
SELECT article_id, datetime, common_tags
FROM (
  SELECT at.article_id, art.datetime, Count(at.article_id) AS common_tags
  FROM article_tags AS at INNER JOIN articles AS art ON at.article_id = art.article_id
  WHERE at.tag_id IN (4,3,1)
  GROUP BY at.article_id
  ORDER BY common_tags DESC, art.datetime DESC
) at1
//IDENTIFY which row article_id X is on in at1
//GET any row below row X in at1
```

This wouldn't be an issue if it weren't for the fact that none of the columns have a static order.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to post this here for anyone else looking for an answer to a similar problem. I had to end up using temporary tables, which turned out to be faster by about half of the time.

I created a temporary table that houses all the results with new, temporary, auto-increment ids so that I could use the ">" operator.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE at_results (
id INTEGER(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
article_id INTEGER(10) NOT NULL,
datetime DATETIME NOT NULL,
common_tags INTEGER NOT NULL)
SELECT at.article_id, art.datetime, Count(at.article_id) AS common_tags
FROM article_tags AS at 
INNER JOIN articles AS art ON at.article_id = art.article_id
WHERE at.tag_id IN (4,3,1)
GROUP BY at.article_id
ORDER BY common_tags DESC, art.datetime DESC;
```

Then I created another temporary table with only the id of the article I needed in the temp table. This is in another table because I found out that MySQL does not let you reference a temporary table more than once. It's a known bug.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE results_article
SELECT id
FROM at_results
WHERE article_id = 23;
```

Then I just pulled any article with an AI id higher than the target article.

```
SELECT at_results.id,article_id, datetime, common_tags
FROM at_results, at_article
WHERE at_results.id > results_article.id
```

This returns the exact results that I was after. I hope this helps someone else. Not being all that proficient with MySQL, it took me a bit to stumble through it.

Justs as a note, I'm not completely sure if this is the most efficient way. As far as I can tell, it's pretty snappy. Someone with more SQL experience would be able to tell you if that's accurate for all situations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't expect this to be very efficient:

```
SELECT at.article_id
     , art.datetime
     , COUNT(at.article_id) AS common_tagged_art
FROM article_tags AS at 
  INNER JOIN articles AS art 
    ON at.article_id = art.article_id
WHERE at.tag_id IN (4, 3, 1)
  AND at.article_id <> 23                         --- parameter: 23
GROUP BY at.article_id
HAVING (COUNT(at.article_id), art.datetime) <=
       ( SELECT COUNT(at2.article_id), art2.datetime
         FROM article_tags AS at2
           INNER JOIN articles AS art2 
             ON at2.article_id = art2.article_id
         WHERE at2.tag_id IN (4, 3, 1)
           AND at2.article_id = 23                 --- parameter: 23
       )
ORDER BY common_tagged_art DESC
       , art.datetime DESC ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I may not be understanding this correctly, but this solution seems to return everything but the specified row for me. If I flip the 23 to any other number, it returns pretty much everything but 23. I'm finding what I'd like to do pretty hard to put into words, so I'm sorry for that.

What I'm looking to do more specifically is count all of the rows of my first query, find which row article_id 23 is in the new count, and return all the rows after the row article_id 23 is on.

Comment: When testing this, did you change the `23` in both places?

Comment: Yes I did. It doesn't appear to matter which article I search for in both fields, it seems to just remove 1 line. I'm getting results before and after the specified parameter. Is this something that would be better suited to creating a temporary table? I was thinking of sorting the results in PHP, but this could return quite a large number of results.

Comment: Can you check again (the update)? The common aliases may were confusing the parser.

Comment: I just tried it again with a little bit different results. I can't seem to identify the pattern of results it returns, but it is not returning the correct data. I actually just solved the issue using temporary tables. I'll post my solution. Thank you for all your help! I'm trying to upvote you, but I'm too new to the site to do so.